# Not being able to change value outside the function scope

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

the duplicate variable is always false even when the user.length is greater than zero . The console prints 'false' first and duplicate record afterwards.

```
var duplicate = false;
userModel.find({mobileNumber: 123456789},(err, user)=>{
    if(user.length > 0){
        console.log("Duplicate Record");
        duplicate = true;
    }
});
console.log(duplicate);
```

Comment: `duplicate` is being set to true, but `console.log` is running _before_ that happens. Common pitfall when getting to grips with callbacks and promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node JS is asynchronous in nature so it will printing

`console.log(duplicate);` first then running find function ,

see logs

```
var duplicate = false;
userModel.find({mobileNumber: 123456789},(err, user)=>{
    console.log('find function called');
    if(user.length > 0){
        console.log("Duplicate Record");
        duplicate = true;
        console.log('duplicate inside',duplicate);
    }
});
console.log('duplicate outside',duplicate);
```

Comment: the value of variable duplicate is always false even when user.length is greater than 0. duplicate inside is true and duplicate outside is false. However I want the variable duplicate to be updated to true outside.

Comment: if you carefully see logs , `duplicate outside : false` ..printed first

Comment: you can use `async / await ` or you can update variable value inside find funtion , and do further operation inside find function after getting user

Answer (score 1):

The reason why duplicate is read as false is that the execution of the console.log is done before the returning of the MongoDB query (that runs the callback to change duplicate).

To solve this race condition, Mongoose can return a [Promise](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) for queries which you can use async/await on for the synchronous behaviour you are expecting.

```
async () => {
    var duplicate = false;
    let users = await userModel.find({mobileNumber: 123456789}).exec();

    if (users.length > 0) {
        console.log("Duplicate record");
        duplicate = true;
    }

    console.log(duplicate); // true

    // more code
}
```